# Extjs 4 MVC load class by widget name

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a widget called `AM.users.Tabs` where I extend a `tabPanel`. How do I load that tabPanel by widget name so I can add tabs to it dynamically? I can set an `id` to it and then use `Ext.getCmp('id').add({...})` but I would like to know if there's a way of getting the component without having to hardcode ids since I have aliases set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like, how do you get the Component object?

If you don't want to use the Ext.getCmp, you can use the new Component query system, which allows you to query components by id or xtype similarly to css.
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.ComponentQuery.html

you can also query a parent component for child components using the same query system:

```
parentPanel.query('myxtype')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load your class by widget name you can use `Ext.createWidget()`

For example if you tabPanel looks like this:

```
Ext.define('AM.users.Tabs', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userstabs',
    ...
});
```

You can call it like this:

```
Ext.createWidget('userstabs', {
    ...
    ...
});
```